Why is oscap claiming "notapplicable" for so many tests on Ubuntu 22?
My team is working on STIG hardening tools for Ubuntu 22 and we're using OpenSCAP to audit a system after hardening.  We're seeing many tests result in notapplicable and don't understand why.  I'm running the following command on the Ubuntu 22 target from the root user:
oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig --report /tmp/stig.html /tmp/scap-security-guide-0.1.75/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds.xml

The profile comes from https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/releases/download/v0.1.75/scap-security-guide-0.1.75.zip
Here's an example of a notapplicable test from the HTML report:


The remediation was performed on the Ubuntu 22 target:
# grep -w action_mail_acct /etc/audit/auditd.conf
action_mail_acct = root
#

and I was expecting this test to result in a pass.
I ran oscap xccdf eval with --verbose INFO and got this information:
Title^M Configure auditd mail_acct Action on Low Disk Space
Rule^M  xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_action_mail_acct
I: oscap: Evaluating definition 'oval:ssg-installed_OS_is_ubuntu2204:def:1': Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I: oscap: Definition 'oval:ssg-installed_OS_is_ubuntu2204:def:1' evaluated as true.
I: oscap: Evaluating definition 'oval:ssg-system_with_kernel:def:1': (null).
I: oscap: Definition 'oval:ssg-system_with_kernel:def:1' evaluated as false.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_action_mail_acct' is not applicable.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_admin_space_left_action'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_admin_space_left_action' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_admin_space_left_percentage'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_admin_space_left_percentage' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file_action'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file_action' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file_action_stig'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_max_log_file_action_stig' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_num_logs'.
I: oscap: Rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_num_logs' is not selected.
I: oscap: Evaluating XCCDF rule 'xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_auditd_data_retention_space_left_action'.
Result^M        notapplicable

There are 145 tests that I believe are failing for the ssg-system_with_kernel definition and I don't understand why.  I tried to track that definition down in ssg-ubuntu2204-ds.xml and believe this is key:
        <linux:dpkginfo_object id="oval:ssg-obj_inventory_test_kernel_installed:obj:1" version="1">
          <linux:name>kernel</linux:name>
        </linux:dpkginfo_object>


So it's looking for an apt package named kernel?  What is that??  How can I get such a test to be evaluated?

I think this is really a bug that belongs to ComplianceAsCode/content.  I built a new profile and the number of not applicable tests dropped significantly.  See https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/discussions/12647 for more.
